# Cant call method from web service

Tags: c#, web-services

Why can't I call web service method like that:

```
ws test = new ws();
test.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
var temp =  test.Method(1, "test");`
```

But this work:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result= reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Web service use https.

I get this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Comment: Well for one thing your first code block does not even have a URL.

Comment: I added like that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx